# Joomla install error INSTL_ERROR_INITIALISE_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm trying to install Joomla 2.5.14 and getting Installation notice `INSTL_ERROR_INITIALISE_SCHEMA`.

Do anyone know the reason for this? Does it required `CREATE ROUTINE` privilege on mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> ((/administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql ))

and ensure that the SQL File for the appropriate version is uploaded. ie. if you're `installing 3.0.3 then make sure the "3.0.3.sql"` is uploaded. Retry The installation Process, it should work ! Good Luck

Comment: Also go to extensions/database e press the "Fix" button

Comment: My administrator directory was in the wrong place. I have corrected it. All good now. Thanks harsh4u.